# How do I setup a read-only proxy for npm?

Tags: node.js, proxy, npm

I would like to run a proxy for the npm, so that `npm install` runs faster. Basically, a tool such as Sinopia is exactly what I'm looking for - but it does too much: It not just acts as a proxy, but also as a private registry. In other words: If you publish a module, it isn't taken to the public registry, but to Sinopia's internal one.

Is it possible to configure Sinopia in a way that it only acts as a caching proxy (or is there another possibility to reach my goal)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this guys will fit your needs [Gemfury](https://gemfury.com/l/npm-registry)

EDIT: I just re-read your question... sorry my answer might not help you but I will leave it here for the sake of a link :)